# find and return a node from a tree in Python

Tags: python, recursion, tree, find, nodes

```
class WNode(object):
    def __init__(self,w):
        self._w=w
        self._content=[]
    def find(self, x):
        if self._w is x:
            return self
        else:
            for i in self._content:
                return i.find(x)
        return None
```

Hi. I'm having troubles to create a method tree.find(self,x) that returns the node with the name x in the tree if x is present (using recursion). The one that i wrote seems to be working only in certain cases(in simple trees with few levels) but in others(especially in larger trees) it returns None even if a node is present. Somebody knows how to create a working find(self,x) method that returns the x node?

Comment: @unixer i want to search the node x. So if it's equal to self._w (the name of the node) it returns the node itself otherwise the program search for a self._w that is equal to x recursively in every child node. But apparently it's not working

Comment: Please add the insertion method and the test case that is failing.

Comment: @blaze I use a function to create the tree. but it doesn't work even on simple tree like: r=WNode('1') r._content=[WNode('2'),WNode('3')]. if i type >>r.find('1') it returns the root node and same with the >>r.find('2'). But >>r.find('3')returns None even if a '3' node is present in r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative answer. Similar to yours and Todd Tao's solution, it implements a DFS. However, once it finishes exploring a branch unsuccessfully, it continues with the next one(s). Your code was searching just the left-most branch.

```
class WNode(object):

    def __init__(self,w):
        self._w=w
        self._content=[]

    def find(self, x):
        if self._w == x:
            return self
        else:
            y = None
            for i in self._content:
                y = i.find(x)
                if y:
                    break
            return y
        return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    r = WNode(1)
    r._content = [WNode(2), WNode(3), WNode(4)]
    for i in xrange(1, 6):
        print('find({}) = {}'.format(i, r.find(i)))
```

Comment: this works if i create manually a tree, but it doesn't works on the tree generated by my function and i don't know why. i checked through a function that prints the trees but the manually created and the function created look just the same :S

Answer (score 1):

That's because your `find` function only looked for the node in the left-most branch. Thinking of an example of a tree as below:

```
      A
    /   \
   B     C
  / \
 D   E
```

Given that you are looking for the node C. Your `find` function looks branch B firstly, then checks D. D has no children so it ends the `for` loop and return `None`. It won't search the other branches as there has been something returned.

Actually if you wanna find a node in a tree, you should implement BFS or DFS algorithm to traverse your tree. Since your `find` function is DFS, I'll code DFS for you:

```
def find(self,x):
  s_list = []
  if self._w is x:
    return self
  else:
    s_list.extend(self._content)
    while s_list:
      node = s_list.pop()
      if node._w is x:
        return node
      else:
        s_list.extend(node._content)
  return None
```

`s_list` works as a search path which records every node `find` should check. If all the nodes has been checked then return `None`.